# C#: How to get a names of subclasses and put them in collection using generic method

Tags: c#, reflection

Here is a problem:

There is a parent class `Class01` which has 2 subclasses: `Subclass0101` and `Subclass0102`. `Class01` and its subclasses are not instantiated yet. We need to

1. Enumerate all subclasses in `Class01`.
2. Put them into the list collection and output the content of that collection.
3. Make that as much generic as possible, using the name of the parent class (like `<Class1>` or so - I am not sure if the notation is correct). That is so that this method would be universal if we have `Class02` with subclasses `SubClass0201` and `SubClass0202`.

Would you be so kind to help we with the code composition as I was unable to compose the existing answers into one project? Thank you very-very much in advance!!!

Here are my intentions:

```
namespace Temp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        // Not sure what to put here
        Show<Class01>

        // Not sure what to put here
        public static Show<T1>
        {
            // and here
        }
    }

    class Class01 {}

    class SubClass0101 : Class01 {}

    class SubClass0102 : Class01 { }

    class Class02 { }

    class SubClass0201 : Class02 { }

    class SubClass0202 : Class02 { }
}
```

Comment: Can you put what have you tried ?

Comment: so do you have a `List<Class01>` or are you just trying to initialize some classes for some reason?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the subclasses are in the same assembly:

```
public static IEnumerable<Type> GetAllSubTypesInSameAssembly(this Type type)
{
    return type.Assembly
               .GetTypes()
               .Where(t => t != type && type.IsAssignableFrom(t));
}
```

Comment: And assuming an interface is a subclass?

Comment: This works for interfaces too.

Comment: That's the problem, OP didn't ask for that.

Comment: Then replace `type.IsAssignableFrom(t)` with `t.IsSubclassOf(type)`. I thought the broader method would be better.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!!! I have not how to resolve the task now, but I've got it has something to do with the reflection, activators and assembles!!! Thanks a lot, will work on it :)